# how to change font family in tailwind element's component

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-elements

I have this select component, I want to set a custom font family as another input's have

```
<select data-te-select-init data-te-select-font="14">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>3
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [the `classes` option(s)](https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/forms/select/#api-section-classes) to apply custom classes to elements of selects. This allows you to use a [font family](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-family) utility class to apply the `font-family` you wish.

For example, we can apply the `mono` `font-family` to the `formOutline` element by using the `data-te-class-form-outline` attribute like:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  darkMode: "class"
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  },
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tw-elements/dist/css/tw-elements.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<select data-te-select-init data-te-select-font="14" data-te-class-form-outline="relative font-mono">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>3

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tw-elements/dist/js/tw-elements.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can I use the font which I added in the tailwind config?

Comment: Indeed, any class can be used.